# Role of diodes and capacitors in the voltage regulator

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzdg7q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have this circuit which is is a Voltage Regulator(the boxes are MC 7812 and MC 7912 and they are voltage Regulators) I would like to ask what is the role of the diodes D1, D2 and the four capacitors (what they do).And one more question, in this circuit i  have as input a dc voltage. What should I add to this circuit so that I have as an input ac voltage 220V at 50 Hz;

Comment: Ask yourself: what does a diode do ? So for D1: what happens if Vin(+) is **1)** -15 V, **2)** 0 V **3)** +15 V. Also google for "rectifier". The capacitors are needed for decoupling, you could see them as very small capacity batteries to keep the voltages stable. You need a **mains transformer** to make a **safe** voltages to use as input. The values of C1 and C2 are ridicolously small. Make them 1000 uF, that should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D1 and D2 just make sure that current will never flow into those regulators the wrong way. Sure there will be a ~0.7V drop across them but they're regulating down to 12V anyway.

It's common practice to put capacitors on the input and output of regulators, I just take values according to the datasheets. They will keep your input and output voltages steady, just a way of reducing ripple and noise. They're actually common practice to put on any IC power input as well, just to keep the power supply clean. That's why you'll see really small .01uF to 10uF caps all over PCBs nowadays.

Now to answer your question on regulating mains, this circuit will not do. Those ICs have an absolute max voltage input of 40Vdc according to the [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC7800-D.PDF). You'll likely want a mains transformer to step the voltage down first to a more manageable level, and then put it through a rectifier, smooth with some caps, pass it into a regulator IC, and call it a day. Something like [image: this]
<sub>(source: [circuitstoday.com](http://www.circuitstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/6v-regulator-circuit-7806_ct.jpg))</sub>

Or if you wanted to go *less* efficient,you can slap a zener diode and resistor to clamp voltage (according to the reverse breakdown of the zener) and limit the current. [image]

Comment: *Or if you wanted to go more analog* Uhm, both solutions are as **analog** as you can get. The zener solution is not recommended as it is very **power inefficient**. For the next level in power efficiency, forget linear regulators and use a switching regulator.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose you're right. Sometimes when I think ICs I just default to a 'less analog' mindset, which I know is very wrong. I'll edit it out to mention that

Comment: @Orotavia I think you mean "discrete" (as in discrete components such as transistors, diodes etc.), as opposed to integrated.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the role of the diodes D1, D2

These diodes function as a full-wave rectifier. In combination with a center-tapped transformer, these two diodes will provide you with a rough DC output, which still varies in magnitude as shown in the below graph (courtesy of radio-electronics.ws).

[image]

If you want to use the circuit that you showed, you will have to use a center-tapped transformer since you need both +Vin and -Vin. This is the circuit, with the current flow shown (again courtesy of radio-electronics.ws).

[image]

> the four capacitors (what they do)

These capactiors smoothen out the signal. As you see in the above graph, the signal has a single polarity, but it still varies in magnitude, the capactior is supposed to smoothen it out.

> And one more question, in this circuit i have as input a dc voltage. What should I add to this circuit so that I have as an input ac voltage 220V at 50 Hz;

The inputs of the circuit are connected to the outputs of a center-tapped transformer.

Comment: The role of D1,D2 - You say "These diodes function as a full-wave rectifier." I say - No they don't. They are there to ensure you don't connect the (DC) supply the wrong way around. How do I know? - the circuit diagram is clearly labelled Vin + and Vin - (i.e. DC inputs). Also the values of C1 and C2 are clearly decoupling (noise) types and not smoothing types which would have a much higher value. **Also** If you want a suitable supply using a CT transformer you need a full wave rectifier with the centre tap connected to 0V. Your diagram only shows a single supply not the split supply needed.

Comment: @JImDearden has right  i think, but thank you both of you

Comment: I see where @JImDearden is coming from. I was too fast to make a conclusion about the circuit. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: No problem we all had to start somewhere - you just need a little bit of editing and it will be fine.